# Spring, Hibernate, HSQLDB: JUnit test case hangs when main thread finishes but second async thread is processing

Tags: spring, multithreading, hibernate, junit, hsqldb

I have a project that uses Spring on top of Hibernate.  HSQLDB serves as the database for JUnit unit tests.  Very often (50% of the time) our builds hang after hitting a specific endpoint.

One of my endpoints that is tested fires off an asynchronous thread to do some cleanup work right before exiting.  It cannot be fired off from the beginning of the endpoint as it depends on the results from the main thread.  Consider the following code:

```
@Transactional
public fooObj findCustomerFoo(Customer cust) {
    CustFooCollection custFooCollection = otherService.getCustomerFoo(cust);
    cleanupFooService.cleanupFoo(custFooCollection.getBadFoo());
    return custFooCollection.getGoodFoo(); //return to the webservice layer that 
    ///populates the response object and kicks it out
}
```

Then in the CleanupFooService you have the cleanupFoo method:

```
@Async
@Transactional
public void cleanupFoo(List<Foo> foo) {
    //1) Pulls foo from DB
    //2) Runs state change and business logic on foo
    //3) Saves objects back in DB
}
```

The idea of the code is that the findCustomerFoo fires off all the required code to pull all my foo objects.  During this some filtering goes on and the foos are filtered into two different categories, good foos to return to the caller and bad foos that require a state change and updating in the repository.

For performance reasons we didn't want to do the cleanup in-line with the request as there is a bit of logic and double checking in there.  That can safely happen behind the scenes.

Our build machine recently had some changes and it exposed an issue with our unit tests.  Very often when this endpoint is hit as part of a test the main thread (that runs findCustomerFoo) finishes before the second thread (cleanupFoo) does.  When that happens the build hangs.  In the logs I can see that cleanupFoo has started calling out to the database but hasn't returned yet.  I do not know if the query is in flight and waiting on the database to respond, if hibernate is still prepping the query, or if hibernate is still dealing with the results.  I do know that the thread is currently in the repository method to handle going to the database.

On our successful builds I can see that the main thread finishes after the async thread.  This is due to a log at the end of the webservice layer.  In the hanging tests this log happens before logs that are present in the async thread.

This code has been running for a while in production without a hiccup.

My running theory is that since the main thread finishes JUnit/Spring starts taking down the HSQLDB causing the second thread to hang.  As it still sees threads running code it does not allow the next unit test or class to start running.

What can I do to stop these hangs?  The original test case author had the in memory database being initialed in @Before annoitated test classes then seeded with data present in a .sql file.  I fixed those to point to the data source described within an xml configuration and used ScriptUtils to run the seed data file.  My theory here was that if I had the setup and tear down of the data source being 100% controlled by spring it might recognize the thread's existence before exiting.  However doing this and removing the after test method that shut down the data source did not work.

Answer (score 0):

First, the database must be live before the operations start and it is not shutdown in the meantime.

If the connections to HSQLDB seem to hang, it is because one connection is in a transaction and another connection is waiting for it to finish. Ensure each set of operations is a transaction that is either committed or rolled back. Note that if that a thread is executing DDL statements, it will wait until all other connections have committed, then lock the whole database during each DDL operation.